# Setting a variable to an operator function

Tags: swift, swift2

Being functions are first class citizens in Swift, I can do this:

```
func someFunc(arg: Int) -> Int { return 1}
let v = someFunc
let out = v(3)
```

And this works as expected. But the same thing can't be applied to operators which seems a little strange, because operators are really just functions.

```
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int { return 1}
let op = + // results in an error
```

Is there an actual way to accomplish assigning an operator to a variable? Or is the only way to wrap the operators in another function which can then be assigned?

Comment: + is ambiguous. Why not use your own operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surrounding the operator with parentheses, and specifying the type explicitly, allows it to parse and typecheck:

```
let op: (Int, Int) -> Int = (+)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem:

```
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int { return 1}
let v = (+) as (Int,Int) -> Int
let out = v(3,4)
print(out)
```

Note that this will actually print 1. Just remove the first line and you get 7.